# how to pass hidden parameters in the url

Tags: codeigniter-3

//i want hidden parameters send in my controler/method
suppose my url link Category/category_product_get/id; ?> but i want id; ?> is hide and pass my controller/method

```
<?php
  if($Category):
   foreach($Category as $main):
?><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Category/category_product_get/<?php echo $main->id; ?><?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

//this is my controller Category.php

```
public function category_product_get($id = null) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can`t hide parameters with url, you can send id using any encryption method like **base64_encode()**.